# Iterate over two folders with the same amount of files

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am new to C++ and I am struggling a bit doing basic things. I am sorry if this question is too stupid or it has been asked somewhere. I tried to search on StackOverflow without success.

I have the following problem: I have two folders with the same number of files, let's call this number N. I would like to do a for loop like the following:

```
for file1 in directory 1 , file2 in directory2: 
   filename_file_folder_1 = get_filename(file1);
   filename_file_folder_2 = get_filename(file2);
```

It must be possible since I would know how to do it probably in Python. Therefore, I expect also C++ to allow this. However, I could not find a solution to this problem yet.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over _one_ folder?

Comment: C++ syntax is different from python and not all constructs are present in both languages. ranges (c++20) include a zip to iterate over two of them simultaneously. Otherwise use an index

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
using std::filesystem::path;
using std::filesystem::directory_iterator;

template<typename F>
void for_each_pair_of_files_in(path dir_a, path dir_b, F f)
{
    using Iter = directory_iterator;
    auto it_a = Iter{dir_a};
    auto it_b = Iter{dir_b};

    for (; it_a != Iter{} && it_b != Iter{}; ++it_a, ++it_b)
        f(*it_a, *it_b);
}

void some_compare(path dir_a, path dir_b);

void do_it()
{
    for_each_pair_of_files_in("a/b", "b/c", some_compare);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rq8GEMsrd

Disclaimer: I don't know what are you doing exactly, also there is no any warranty that both iterators will have some specific order, so probably some element matching is needed.

In C++20, there is [`std::ranges::views::zip`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view), which is equivalent to Python's `zip`, but from [what I've tried](https://godbolt.org/z/46M4Pd8xW) there is no compiler which has this feature yet.

Comment: There is no need for the lambda in your `for_each_pair_of_files_in()` call, since `some_compare` is compatible with the signature that `for_each_pair_of_files_in()` is expecting, eg: `for_each_pair_of_files_in("a/b", "b/c", some_compare);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau from code readability point of view yes, but enforcing lambda to call a function enables some optimizations which are not available when function pointer is passed directly.

Comment: @MarekR Oh I didn't know that. Could you explain how using lambda enables optimization? If that's possible, then why it's not possible to optimize if a function pointer is passed directly?

Comment: When you pass function pointer template parameter is defined by function signature, not by a function instance. So optimizer must instantiate template with function pointer in case someone will pass function with same signature. In case of lambda each lambda has own type so optimizer can inline lambda info template instance and in this case it just calls `some_compare` so optimizer can simply inline this function without pointer indirection. This is the reason Rust designers made each function to have own type even when function have same signature.

Answer (score 2):

If you know both directories have the same number of entries you may be able to walk them using `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` (or simply `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` if you do not want to recursively go into every subdirectory).

The code below:

- uses `std::transform` to walk both directories as if they were two ranges, and, for each iteration,
- gets a directory entry from each directory tree, and
- adds the path of both directory entries to a `std::vector`;
- then prints the vector.

For two input folder trees such as:

```
/blah1                         
|-- /aaa
|   |-- a1
|-- foo1

/blah2
|-- b1
|-- b2
|-- foo2
```

It outputs:

```
[/blah1/aaa, /blah2/b1]
[/blah1/aaa/a1, /blah2/b2]
[/blah1/foo1, /blah2/foo2]
```

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  // back_inserter
#include <numeric>  // transform
#include <utility>  // pair
#include <vector>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    const fs::path path_1{ "/blah1" };
    const fs::path path_2{ "/blah2" };
    std::vector<std::pair<fs::path, fs::path>> v{};
    std::transform(
        fs::recursive_directory_iterator{ path_1 }, {},
        fs::recursive_directory_iterator{ path_2 },
        std::back_inserter(v),
        [](auto& entry1, auto& entry2) {
            return std::pair<fs::path, fs::path>{ entry1.path(), entry2.path() };
        }
    );
    for (auto& p : v)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("[{}, {}]\n",
            p.first.generic_string(), p.second.generic_string());
    }
}
```

Notice [the iteration order is unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) for `std::recursive_directory_iterator` (the same applies to `std::directory_iterator`).

---

Should you need to work on sorted lists of entries, I would:

- Walk each folder separately, keeping the list of entries in a `std::vector`.
- Sort both vectors of entries.
- Then proceed as shown above, walking both vectors of entries at the same time.

The code below walks two folders and prints the sorted entries for both of them. It uses a predicate to filter the entries to print (e.g. all of them, or just regular files).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // copy_if, sort
#include <filesystem>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  // back_inserter, ostream_iterator
#include <numeric>  // transform
#include <vector>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

template <typename UnaryPredicate>
auto get_entries_sorted_if(const fs::path& path, UnaryPredicate&& pred)
{
    std::vector<fs::path> entries{};
    std::copy_if(fs::recursive_directory_iterator{ path }, {}, std::back_inserter(entries),
        std::forward<UnaryPredicate>(pred));
    std::sort(std::begin(entries), std::end(entries));
    return entries;
}

template <typename UnaryPredicate>
auto print_all_entries_sorted_if(const fs::path& path_1, const fs::path& path_2, UnaryPredicate&& pred) {
    auto entries_1{ get_entries_sorted_if(path_1, std::forward<UnaryPredicate>(pred)) };
    auto entries_2{ get_entries_sorted_if(path_2, std::forward<UnaryPredicate>(pred)) };

    std::transform(std::cbegin(entries_1), std::cend(entries_1),
        std::cbegin(entries_2),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout),
        [](auto& entry_1, auto& entry_2) {
            return std::format("[{}, {}]\n",
                entry_1.generic_string(), entry_2.generic_string());
        });
};

int main()
{
    const fs::path path_1{ "/blah1" };
    const fs::path path_2{ "/blah2" };

    auto print_all_entries_sorted = [](const fs::path& p1, const fs::path& p2) {
        print_all_entries_sorted_if(p1, p2, [](auto& p) { return true; });
    };
    auto print_all_files_sorted = [](const fs::path& p1, const fs::path& p2) {
        print_all_entries_sorted_if(p1, p2, [](auto& p) { return fs::is_regular_file(p); });
    };

    std::cout << "Printing all entries sorted...\n";
    print_all_entries_sorted(path_1, path_2);
    std::cout << "\nPrinting all files sorted...\n";
    print_all_files_sorted(path_1, path_2);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Printing all entries sorted...
//   [/blah1/aaa, /blah2/b1]
//   [/blah1/aaa/a1, /blah2/b2]
//   [/blah1/foo1, /blah2/foo2]
//   
//   Printing all files sorted...
//   [/blah1/aaa/a1, /blah2/b1]
//   [/blah1/foo1, /blah2/b2]
```

Notice the number of entries should be the same after the predicate is applied, and this code doesn't check that. That's why `/blah2/foo2` is not shown when printing all files sorted. If you called this code with `print_all_files_sorted(path_2, path_1)`, you would have a problem. That would be easily handled with a simple check before the `std::transform`:

```cpp
    if (entries_1.size() != entries_2.size())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: different number of entries.\n";
        return;
    }
```

Comment: this is miss use of `std::transform` I do not think it will compile.

Comment: I just tested it on my VS2022. Why do you think this is a misuse?

Comment: Ha it never come to me that `std::transform` can accept two input iterator ranges. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries! It's really a powerful tool. And `std::transform_reduce` goes a step further. However, as you mentioned in your answer, `zip` will be the next best thing! :)

Comment: Why `recursive_directory_iterator` and not just `directory_iterator`? The OP didn't say anything about wanting to walk through subfolders, only files.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's a good point, yes, which I actually didn't consider. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @rturrado, thanks a lot for the time you have taking writing and thinking about the answer. I really appreciate it. I used what you wrote and now the only problem is (as you mention) the order of the files in the two folders. I would like to find a way to pick the files in alphabetical order. I will look for a way to do it. If you have any hints please let me know. I know about `std::sort` but I will need to understand how to apply it here (as I said, i am  C++ newbie)

Comment: @desmond13 Glad to be helpful! I've updated my answer with a version that prints the files alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for: (assuming directory1/2 are vectors/arrays)

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
    file1 = directory1[i];
    file2 = directory2[i];
    // can use file1 and file2 however you want now
}
```